# Why is the button not located on the right?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightning-layouts

I need to put the `New` button on the right, but I can't. What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header_object-home">
        <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:work_order_type" alternative-text="Work Types"></lightning-icon>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small">
            <div class="page-section page-header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_label">Work Types</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Work Types</h2>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="end">
            <lightning-button label="New" onclick={handleNew}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `horizontal-align="spread"` to the lightning layout to spread out the items to the left and right sides.

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout horizontal-align="spread" class="slds-page-header slds-page-header_object-home">
        <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:work_order_type" alternative-text="Work Types"></lightning-icon>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small">
            <div class="page-section page-header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_label">Work Types</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Work Types</h2>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="end">
            <lightning-button label="New" onclick={handleNew}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```